# How is key press event processed in the system in depth (brightness keys not working on lenovo laptop)?

Tags: linux, drivers, keyboard, lenovo-laptop, acpi

**Context first:**
I am on Ideapad 330-17ICH and some <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys simply don't work - microphone toggle, touchpad toggle, airplane mode, camera toggle and brightness up/down (the ones I need the most).

I am trying to find a way to fix the problem... but to fix it, I have to understand which part exactly is "broken". For that I need to understand what exactly (and in what order) happens inside my computer whenever I press the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> combination to decrease the brightness.

I already looked up Computerphile series "What happens when you press a key", but it is too general and doesn't really help me. Also found [that thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830948/lenovo-ideapad-brightness-keys-not-generating-any-events-in-ubuntu-16-04-1), but I am not sure what may happen when I use those commands, and if I wont fcuk up my system by accident.

I found info that something like ACPI tables/registers/BIOS/drivers exist but I didn't find anything useful when diving down the ACPI hole. I recognize that some keys may be recognized on such low level that it is impossible to fix it without hardware tampering (for example <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> for keyboard LEDs is probably a purely hardware solution), but I am NOT convinced that this is irreparable.

I have no way to check if those keys work on Windows, but I am pretty sure they do (why would Lenovo add functions to the keyboard that don't work on Windows?). From that I assume that this issue CAN be fixed somehow on Linux given enough time and knowledge, but I absolutely have to know where to start looking.

**So how does keypress processing chain look like?** Is it something like a IRQ -> BIOS-> ACPI -> ACPI driver -> kernel -> keyboard driver -> X -> app? Am I missing some steps (I probably am)? Please explain in details how it works and if it may be something fixable where to look for more info.

**My device**, taken from `neofetch`: (ubuntu is pretty much stock, I didn't even replace WM).

```
------------------ 
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: 81FL Lenovo ideapad 330-17ICH 
Kernel: 5.4.0-91-generic 
Uptime: 5 hours, 25 mins 
Packages: 3711 (dpkg), 20 (flatpak), 18 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Yaru-dark 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-8750H (12) @ 4.100GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630 
Memory: 9679MiB / 19892MiB
```

Also `sudo showkey --scancode` didn't produce any input when pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

---

**@EDIT** More context:
I've started watching `/proc/interrupts` and pressing keys at random:
`sudo watch -d -n .1 cat /proc/interrupts`
When pressing faulty keys <kbd>Fn</kbd>+[<kbd>F4</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>] there was no change to the line (`-->` inserted to separate CPUs from comment):
`1: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 40191 0 0 0 0 --> IR-IO-APIC 1-edg i8042`
which normally changes when any other keyboard key is pressed. I can't really reason about other lines because they either stay dead or change too frequently.

Comment: It's all up to the software. Of the keys you mentioned, only the brightness keys have a universally recognized function. It's still up to the software to actually "do the thing".

Comment: @DanielB that's also my train of though... but on which software level? IRQ? BIOS? ACPI? Kernel? Driver? X.Org? WM? That's the question.